# How to show a jquery mobile popup at the bottom of the page?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm not quite familiar with neither css nor jquery mobile.

Not sure whether I'm in a right direction but that closest I've got so far is to manage to stick the popup at the top of the page by assigning bottom: 0px; to .ui-popup-container

But this outer wrapper has inline style that overwrite the top position therefore I couldn't stick it to bottom.

```
{
    max-width: 432px;
    top: 272px;
    left: 125px;
}
```

Anyone can shed some lights for me?

Thanks.

Comment: Prob don't want to mess with the CSS.  Place an empty element at the bottom with absolute positioning.  Then use a selector when setting the position.  See here:  http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#option-positionTo

Comment: @Dave I've tried playing around with some hidden anchor element for position to setting for the popup. But the wrapper still float the popup div a bit higher from the bottom. Overwriting the inline css with !important works, but I'm still looking for more native solutions.

Comment: I wonder if that's the tolerance you're seeing, which is by default 30px 15px;  "A tolerance from the edges of the window (15px from each of the sides and 30px from the top and the bottom) will be observed when the popup fits inside the window. Tall popups are allowed to overflow the top and bottom edges of the window. Those parts of the popup can be viewed by manually scrolling the document. This tolerance can be configured via the tolerance option."  See here:  http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#option-tolerance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with CSS. Set the `top` to auto and the `bottom` to 0:

```
.ui-popup-container {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    top: auto !important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    width: 100%;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/umgML/)**